# SQL Query to get the users who bought the items from the given list and no other items (unwanted) needs to be present in that items;

Tags: sql, sql-server

Users table has two fields user id and item id respectively and require to print only those users having only those items in the given list
the given List is 7,8,9

Users is the table name

```
usersid    itemid
-----------------
123        - 8
123        - 8
123        - 8

222        - 7
222        - 8
222        - 9

333        - 7
333        - 9

444        - 8
444        - 7
444        - 6

555        - 9
555        - 9
555        - 5

666         - 8

766         - 6

888        -1
888        -7
888        -8

999         -7
999         -9
```

The expected answer is

```
123,
222,
333,
666,
999
```

Several attempt to solve this has resulted in producing incorrect answers.
Kindly help with the logic

Thanks for your great time and contribution

Comment: It would be helpful if you could format your example data and to show the SQL you have attempted.

Comment: *"Several attempt to solve this has resulted in producing incorrect answers."* and why were those attempts? Why didn't they work?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Your approach will vary depending on your exact rules. For the scenario in your question you want UserIds that have no rows for ItemIds other than 7, 8 or 9, so you can use:

```
SELECT  t.UsersID
FROM    (VALUES
            (123, 8), (123, 8), (123, 8), (222, 7), (222, 8), (222, 9), 
            (333, 7), (333, 9), (444, 8), (444, 7), (444, 6), (555, 9), 
            (555, 9), (555, 5), (666, 8), (766, 6), (888, 1), (888, 7), 
            (888, 8), (999, 7), (999, 9)
        ) AS T (UsersID, ItemID)
GROUP BY t.UsersID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ItemID NOT IN (7, 8, 9) THEN t.ItemID END) = 0;
```

If you want to know the users with all of 7, 8, and 9 and no other values then you might use:

```
SELECT  t.UsersID
FROM    (VALUES
            (123, 8), (123, 8), (123, 8), (222, 7), (222, 8), (222, 9), 
            (333, 7), (333, 9), (444, 8), (444, 7), (444, 6), (555, 9), 
            (555, 9), (555, 5), (666, 8), (766, 6), (888, 1), (888, 7), 
            (888, 8), (999, 7), (999, 9)
        ) AS t(UsersID, ItemID)
GROUP BY t.UsersID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.ItemID) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t.ItemID IN (7, 8, 9) THEN t.ItemID END)
AND COUNT(DISTINCT t.ItemID) = 3;
```

*N.B. If your table is already constraint for the tuple `UsersId, ItemId` to be unique then using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is not necessary, you can simply use `COUNT(...)` as you already know that ItemIds are distinct*

If you need to return the ItemIds as well, then you may find it easier to use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.

```
WITH T AS
(   SELECT  UsersID, ItemID
    FROM    (VALUES
                (123, 8), (123, 8), (123, 8), (222, 7), (222, 8), (222, 9), 
                (333, 7), (333, 9), (444, 8), (444, 7), (444, 6), (555, 9), 
                (555, 9), (555, 5), (666, 8), (766, 6), (888, 1), (888, 7), 
                (888, 8), (999, 7), (999, 9)
            )  AS t(UsersID, ItemID)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    T AS T2 
            WHERE   T2.UsersId = T.UsersId 
            AND     T2.ItemID NOT IN (7, 8, 9)
        );
```

The linked article goes through various other techniques and scenarios, but the above should be enough to get you started.